# save current post and edit next one

Tags: cakephp, redirect

I'm trying to emulate the following working scenario. On the edit stage of a cakephp blog post I need to add the `Prev` & `Next` buttons. When I press `Next`, I need the current form to be saved and the next blog post to appear in edit mode.

In my edit form I have:

```
//form create
echo $this->Html->link('Next', 
    array('controller' => 'posts', 'action' => 'next', $id, $nextId), 
    array('class' => 'btn', 'escape' => false)
  );
//inputs
//form submit
```

and the `next()` method in `PostsController`, looks like this:

```
  <?php
  // ... 
  public function next($id = null, $nextId = null) {
    $this->Post->id = $id;
    if (!$this->Post->exists()) {
        throw new NotFoundException('Invalid id', 'info');
    }
  debug($this->request);
    //if ($this->request->is('post') || $this->request->is('put')) {
        if ($this->Post->save($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash('saved', 'ok');
            $this->redirect(
              array('controller'=>'posts', 
                    'action' => 'edit', 
                    $nextId));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash('cant save', 'error');
        }
    //}
}
```

At the first sight, `request->data` is empty and I don't know why. Then, the question is: is my logic OK? Can I solve my problem using this approach?

Can you share a better solution?

Comment: i usually do it the other way around. I first save the form and then find out what the next id is and redirect to this one.

Answer (score 1):

@nahri is right in that you're not submitting the form data by clicking on your previous or next links.

To keep it simple, you should include multiple submit buttons within your form to ensure the data gets submitted but give them appropriate names so you can handle the request accordingly in your controller:

*In your view:*

```
echo $this->Form->submit('Next', array('name'=>'next'));
echo $this->Form->submit('Previous', array('name'=>'previous'));
```

*In your controller*

```
if($this->request->is('post') && (isset($this->data['next']) || isset($this->data['previous')) {
    // save post as draft...
    // then redirect 
    if(isset($this->data['next'])){
        $this->redirect(array('action' => 'next'));
    }else{
        $this->redirect(array('action' => 'previous'));
    }
}
```

The code above should illustrate the principle of perhaps one way you could implement the functionality you require - you need to customize it for your application.

Remember, you're still posting the form back as if you were actually saving it (even to the same action), the only difference is that the presence of either your previous or next buttons is appended to the form data.

I suspect that if this doesn't do it in the manner that you were hoping for, then you're likely going to have to AJAX the form back to the server and then redirect the window in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

You're not submitting your form, which is why `$this->request->data` is empty.

You could do it like this:

```
$this->Form->create('YourModelName', array('action' => 'next'));

// here you want to include your $next value as a hidden form field
$this->Form->input('next', array('type' => 'hidden', 'value' => $next));

// rest of your form
//..  

$this->Form->end(__('Submit'));
```

Then you can use your logic in the controller to save the data and redirect to the next edit page. (the value will be in `$this->request->data['YourModelName']['next']`).

Comment: ty for your answer but I need my form data to be triggered when I press `prev`, `next` or `submit` , not on next button press only.

Comment: Then include multiple submit buttons and check in your controller code which was clicked.